# $\dim_k(\mathfrak{m/ m^2}) = \dim_k(\frak m_m/m_m^2)?$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A[X]$ be the coordinate ring of an irreducible affine variety, $X$, over an algebraically closed field, $k$. Let $\frak m$ be the vanishing ideal of $p\in X$, and let $\frak m_\frak m$ be the maximal ideal in the local ring $A[X]_\frak m$. Is the $k$-dimension of the $k$-vector space $\frak m/\frak m^2$ the same as that of $\frak m_m/m_m^2$?

I ask because I was reading a proof that the map $$Hom_k(\mathfrak{m_m/m_m^2}, k)\rightarrow Der_k(A[X], k),~~\delta \mapsto (f \mapsto \delta (f-f(p)))$$

is a vector space isomorphism.  And the same proof seems to work replacing $\frak m_m$ with $\frak m$. But its puzzling because the quotient of the  localization map $\frak m/m^2 \rightarrow \frak m_m/m_m^2$ doesn't seem surjective, in general.

Comment: The localization map above is an isomorphism. Please recheck your calculations.

Comment: @Mohan So for $m\in \frak m$, $r\notin \frak m$, I want $m/1 - m/r = m\cdot  (r-1)/r \in \frak m_m^2$. So if I knew $r-1 \in \frak m$, I would be okay...

Comment: Why do you want what you say? For example, if $2\not\in\mathfrak{m}$, do you really expect $m/1-m/2$ to be in the square?

Comment: He's trying to find something in $\mathfrak m$ that maps to $m/r$.  But $m$ is probably not going to work.

Comment: Right..........

Comment: I tried to work this out and it's a little harder than I thought.  Since this isn't true for general rings, what you'll probably need to do is choose an embedding of $X$ into affine space and work explicitly with polynomials.  E.g. your point is the origin, and $\mathfrak m$ consists of all polynomial functions on $X$ with zero constant term.

Comment: @D_S Thanks. But it is certainly true, right?

Comment: It is definitely true.  And you already have a proof yourself by showing that the same proof with the derivations works with $A[X]$ or its localization.

Comment: Thanks again. I only ask because I've noticed that I occasionally have the amazing super power of proving false statements :)

Comment: Notice that the result is valid for a completely  arbitrary maximal ideal of a completely arbitrary commutative ring. The properties "irreducible affine variety" and  "algebraically closed field" are irrelevant. This is clear from Mohan's proof.

Comment: This question is very odd.

Comment: @PastorDoctorMartinSsempa we do not want this sickness here on mse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given $r\not\in\mathfrak{m}$, there exists an $s$ such that $rs\equiv 1\bmod\mathfrak{m}$, since modulo a maximal ideal, we have a field and any non-zero element is invertible. Then, easy to check that $sm-m/r=(rsm-m)/r=(rs-1)m/r$ is indeed in the square of the maximal ideal, since $m\in\mathfrak{m}$ proving surjectivity. That is, $sm\mapsto m/r$ under the map from $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$ to its localization at $\mathfrak{m}$.